# Is there a way to sort ip-addresses in a dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, ip-address

I am using Pandas to sort a data frame.
A handful of the columns are IP addresses that need to be sorted.

Is there a way to sort by IP addresses with Pandas easily? Is it possible to create a custom function I can use with Pandas to sort IP addresses?

I was able to sort a list of IP addresses, however I am having difficulty figuring out how to create custom sort functions with Pandas. Is there a way to incorporate inet_aton from the socket module?

I was able to accomplish this task on a list outside of Pandas:

```
list_of_ips = ['192.168.204.111', '10.10.10.10', '172.16.32.6', '1.1.1.1', '8.8.8.100']
sorted(list_of_ips, key=lambda ip: struct.unpack("!L", inet_aton(ip))[0])
['1.1.1.1', '8.8.8.100', '10.10.10.10', '172.16.32.6', '192.168.204.111']
```

I expect a column of IP-addresses in a data frame to be sorted with Pandas.

Comment: you could add column with values `inet_aton` to dataframe and then you can sort it with pandas. Instead of `inet_aton` you can also put [ipaddress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In pandas we have `argsort`

```
df.iloc[np.argsort(list(map(socket.inet_aton,list_of_ips)))]
```

Comment: Thank you sir, this worked perfectly! Note, as this was a data frame, I replaced "list_of_ips" with my Data Frame's dictionary key value, and it worked as well --> `df.iloc[np.argsort(list(map(socket.inet_aton,df.sip)))]`

Answer (score 0):

The **cyberpandas** library could be useful in this case. Works well with pandas.

**IPArray**

This is the container for your IPAddress data. Even you can sort both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses.

```
In [1]: from cyberpandas import IPArray

In [2]: import pandas as pd

In [3]: arr = IPArray(['192.168.1.1',
   ...:                '2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334'])
   ...: 

In [4]: arr
Out[4]: IPArray(['192.168.1.1', '2001:db8:85a3::8a2e:370:7334'])
```

Find the official documentation from the following link

https://cyberpandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#usage